The derivative of a biholomorphism to the unit disc is always bounded.
I am studying about biholomorophisms on complex plane and knew about Riemann mapping theorem and Carathéodory's theorem. After that, I wondered if the following statement is correct.
Let $D$ be a domain on complex plane and $f(x)$ be a biholomorphism from $D$ to the unit disc. Is $f'(x)$ always bounded?
I tried to solve it by using Schwarz lemma. But it didn't work well. Can someone prove this claim or find a counterexample of it?

Hint: Consider the mapping from the plane with the negative real axis removed to the unit disk.

Thank you for your hint, @MartinR.  I could construct the counterexample $f(z)=\frac{{\sqrt{z}+1}}{\sqrt{z}-1}.$ Now I wonder if this claim holds true if we assume that $D$ is bounded. What can we say about that?

The unit disk with the interval $(-1, 0]$ removed should work as a counterexample, because the conformal mapping to the unit disk roughly behaves like $\sqrt z$ near the origin.

Thank you! You really helped me.
